# AWS Lambda - MongoDB resource optimization

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, dbconnection

I'm building facebook chatbot using AWS Lambda and MongoDB. At the moment, my application is pretty simple but I'm trying to nail down the basics before I move onto the complex stuff.

I understand AWS Lambda is stateless but I've read adding below line in handler along with variables initialized outside handler, I don't have to establish DB connection on every request.

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

(I've read this from this article; https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/optimizing-aws-lambda-performance-with-mongodb-atlas-and-nodejs)

I'm adding my entire code below

```
'use strict'

const
axios = require('axios'),
mongo = require('mongodb'),
MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient,
assert = require('assert');

var VERIFY_TOKEN = process.env.VERIFY_TOKEN;
var PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN;
var MONGO_DB_URI = process.env.MONGO_DB_URI;
let cachedDb = null;
let test = null;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
var method = event.context["http-method"];
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
console.log("test :: " + test);
if (!test) {
    test = "1";
}

// process GET request --> verify facebook webhook
if (method === "GET") {
    var queryParams = event.params.querystring;
    var rVerifyToken = queryParams['hub.verify_token']
    if (rVerifyToken === VERIFY_TOKEN) {
        var challenge = queryParams['hub.challenge'];
        callback(null, parseInt(challenge))
    } else {
        var response = {
            'body': 'Error, wrong validation token',
            'statusCode': 403
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }
    // process POST request --> handle message
} else if (method === "POST") {
    let body = event['body-json'];

    body.entry.map((entry) => {
        entry.messaging.map((event) => {
            if (event.message) {
                if (!event.message.is_echo && event.message.text) {
                    console.log("BODY\n" + JSON.stringify(body));
                    console.log("<<MESSAGE EVENT>>");
                    // retrieve message
                    let response = {
                            "text": "This is from webhook response for \'" + event.message.text + "\'"
                        }
                        // facebook call
                    callSendAPI(event.sender.id, response);

                    // store in DB
                    console.time("dbsave");
                    storeInMongoDB(event, callback);
                }
            } else if (event.postback) {
                console.log("<<POSTBACK EVENT>>");
            } else {
                console.log("UNHANDLED EVENT; " + JSON.stringify(event));
            }

        })
    })
}
}

function callSendAPI(senderPsid, response) {
    console.log("call to FB");
    let payload = {
        recipient: {
            id: senderPsid
        },
        message: response
    };
    let url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=${PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`;
    axios.post(url, payload)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("response ::: " + response);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

function storeInMongoDB(messageEnvelope, callback) {
    console.log("cachedDB :: " + cachedDb);
    if (cachedDb && cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected()) {
        sendToAtlas(cachedDb.db("test"), messageEnvelope, callback);
    } else {
        console.log(`=> connecting to database ${MONGO_DB_URI}`);
        MongoClient.connect(MONGO_DB_URI, function(err, db) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            cachedDb = db;
            sendToAtlas(db.db("test"), messageEnvelope, callback);
        });
    }
}

function sendToAtlas(db, message, callback) {
    console.log("send to Mongo");
    db.collection("chat_records").insertOne({
        facebook: {
            messageEnvelope: message
        }
    }, function(err, result) {
        if (err != null) {
            console.error("an error occurred in sendToAtlas", err);
            callback(null, JSON.stringify(err));
        } else {
            console.timeEnd("dbsave");
            var message = `Inserted a message into Atlas with id: ${result.insertedId}`;
            console.log(message);
            callback(null, message);
        }
    });
}
```

I did everything as instructed and referenced a few more similar cases but somehow on every request, "cachedDb" value is not saved from previous request and the app is establishing the connection all over again.

Then I also read that there is no guarantee the Lambda function is using the same container on multiple requests so I made another global variable "test". "test" variable value is logged "1" from the second request which means it's using the same container but again, "cachedDb" value is not saved.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you console log cachedDb after the line cachedDb = db what gets output?

Comment: @KMo I got "undefined". But I solved it now. I think it was because on a few cases like "read" or "delivery" event I didn't return callback so the process kept getting killed before I try anything.

Answer (score -1):

In short AWS Lambda function is not a permanently running service of any kind.

So, far I know AWS Lambda works on idea - "one container processes one request at a time".

It means when request comes and there is available running container for the Lambda function AWS uses it, else it starts new container.

If second request comes when first container executes Lambda function for first request AWS starts new container.
and so on...

Then there is no guarantee in what container (already running or new one) Lambda function will be executed, so... new container opens new DB connection.

Of course, there is an inactivity period and no running containers will be there after that. All will start over again by next request.